# Observe if min or max date is hit in UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I'm interested in registering, if the user hit the min or max date while using a UIDatePicker. 
Is there a way to do so?
Thanks.

Comment: You can compare the `date` property with `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a method that listens to value changes in the date picker itself:

`[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerDateChanged:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Then, in the method, compare the date of the date picker with the min or max date:

```
- (void)datePickerDateChanged:(UIDatePicker*)picker {
    if ([picker.date compare:picker.maximumDate] == NSOrderedSame) {
        // max
    } else if ([picker.date compare:picker.minimumDate] == NSOrderedSame) {
        // min
    }
}
```

Hope that hepls. Good luck!

Comment: Why not using `isEqualToDate` instead of `compare`?

Comment: Just a matter of taste.